# Excel: Add Data to the Table after hitting the Add Record Button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to recording Macros and I need help in writing VBA code to do the following:

I have 2 different areas in my excel.  The first part is where data is being keyed, and the 2nd part is the table where I want the keyed data moved over to the next available row once "Add Record" button has been clicked.

Tab Name: TPE Report

[image: 1]

Unfortunately, I didn't get too far in getting any codes.

Comment: Please update your screepshot to include row / column heading. It is important to refers cells.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome updated, can you see it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `2nd part` is **NOT** a table (which is created by Insert>>Table), the code is simple.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sTabName As String, aValue
    sTabName = "TPE Report"
    Set rCell = Sheets(sTabName).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    aValue = Array([c9], [c11], [c13], [e9], [e11], [e13])
    rCell.Resize(1, 6).Value = aValue
End Sub
```

---

If `2nd part` is a table, let's assume there is only one table (ListObject) on sheet "TPE Report". Of course, you can refers a table object with its name (e.g "TPETable").

**Option1:**

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim oTable As ListObject, rCell As Range
    Dim sTabName As String, aValue
    sTabName = "TPE Report"
    ' Get the first table
    Set oTable = Sheets(sTabName).ListObjects(1)
    ' Get table with name
    ' Set oTable = Sheets(sTabName).ListObjects("TPETable")
    With oTable
        ' using the 1st column in table to check if its empty or not
        Set rCell = .DataBodyRange.Cells(1).End(xlDown)
        If rCell.Row = .ListRows.Count + .HeaderRowRange.Row Then
            ' Expand table if it is full
            .ListRows.Add
            Set rCell = Cells(.ListRows.Count + .HeaderRowRange.Row, rCell.Column)
        Else
            Set rCell = rCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
    aValue = Array([c9], [c11], [c13], [e9], [e11], [e13])
    rCell.Resize(1, 6).Value = aValue
End Sub
```

**Option2:**

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim oTable As ListObject, rCell As Range
    Dim sTabName As String, aValue
    sTabName = "TPE Report"
    Set oTable = Sheets(sTabName).ListObjects(1)
    ' using the 2nd column to check if its empty or not
    Set rCell = Sheets(sTabName).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
    If Len(Trim(rCell)) = 0 Then
        Set rCell = rCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        With oTable
            .ListRows.Add
            Set rCell = Cells(.ListRows.Count + .HeaderRowRange.Row, rCell.Column)
        End With
    End If
    aValue = Array([c9], [c11], [c13], [e9], [e11], [e13])
    rCell.Resize(1, 6).Value = aValue
End Sub
```

**Update**

Add a function to loop through all table columns to find the last row with data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim oTable As ListObject, rCell As Range
    Dim sTabName As String, aValue
    Dim lLastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    sTabName = "TPE Report"
    Set oSht = Sheets(sTabName)
    Set oTable = oSht.ListObjects(1)
    lLastRow = GetLastRow(oTable)
    With oTable
        If lLastRow = .ListRows.Count + .HeaderRowRange.Row Then
            .ListRows.Add
        End If
        aValue = Array([c9], [c11], [c13], [e9], [e11], [e13])
        oSht.Cells(lLastRow + 1, .Range(1).Column).Resize(1, 6).Value = aValue
    End With
End Sub

' Check all columns in the table to get the last row #
Function GetLastRow(oTab As ListObject) As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, rCell As Range, i As Integer
    Dim iColStart As Integer
    Dim iColEnd As Integer
    ' loop through the last row of DataBodyRange
    With oTab.DataBodyRange
        For Each rCell In .Rows(.Rows.Count).Cells
            If Len(Trim(rCell)) = 0 Then
                Set rCell = rCell.End(xlUp)
                If rCell.Row > lRow Then lRow = rCell.Row
            Else
                lRow = rCell.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With
    GetLastRow = lRow
End Function
```

Comment: It works now!!!! thank you so much for your help! now I just need to understand your code.  Thank you thank you thank you!!!!

Comment: hello!  I saw you mentioned that it is using column B to check if its empty or not, how do I adjust that to look at column C instead?

Comment: oh it's overwriting the last data with no FIPS code (I entered manually on the table) rather than going to the next available row.

Comment: Do you prefer to use Option1 or 2? I can update it to check all columns in table to locate the last row.

Comment: I like option 2 =)

Comment: Perfect! the updated code works great!!!! YOU ROCK! thank you soooo much!!!!

Comment: The `GetLastRow` function has been updated for better efficiency.